# Netstream.publish fails to publish live data when embeded in html but works fine when tested in flash professional

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, cdn, live-streaming, netstream

I have a small as3 app which is supposed to be embedded in a page and will push webcam and audio to a fastly ingest server. When I test it using ctrl+enter in flash professional it works perfectly, when I embed it in the html page it acts like its working fine, except fastly doesn't receive the stream.

My understanding is I don't need a crossdomain.xml because I am pushing to fastly and not loading from it.

I feel like I am missing something simple, but for the life of me I don't know what it is.

Comment: Does the browser testing involve the html file being on your hard drive? If so try running it from your website server. Also did you get any error like "A Flash Application is trying to communicate with the Internet?" If so you need to set permissions for your testing folder

Comment: Its running from the web server and I get no errors from flash or via the web browser itself. Essentially it all appears as if it is working, except for the fact that its not.